# my website is unable to display text in other language

Tags: php, html, select, text

I have a sign up page with select option: country.

I copy the list of country from Google account registration because it would be better to display both English and the local language.

But my website is unable to display many other language, it shows some random code.

- Afghanistan (‫افغانستان‬‎)
- Åland Islands (Åland)
- Albania (Shqipëri)
- Algeria (‫الجزائر‬‎)
- Hong Kong (香港)
- Iran (‫ایران‬‎)
- Iraq (‫العراق‬‎)
- Vietnam (Việt Nam)
- Western Sahara (‫الصحراء الغربية‬‎)
- Yemen (‫اليمن‬‎)

Example,for Hong Kong, instead of `香港`, it display `é¦™æ¸¯`

There are lot more but I do not want to display all of them.

I am using php and xampp in my website. Am I missing any setting or plugins?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It has nothing to do with xampp, windows 8.1 or sublime text2.

Comment: maybe take a look at [UTF8](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Comment: probably charset is not set in html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its a problem with your charset add this

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Between your `<head> </head>` tags

If you use a database, for example mysql make sure to change it there too

Comment: Better use `<meta />` instead of `<meta>` although in HTML, nothing happens when you use another.

Comment: it's a void element I think it isn't necessary to add the /.
In the w3 documentation they have examples and don't use the slash
http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element

Answer (score 0):

Add meta tag with charset in head section.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should deliver your pages UTF-8 encoded:

1. Store your HTML page UTF-8 encoded with your editor.
2. Add the meta information to your HTML header like `<meta charset="UTF-8">`
3. Set your database connection to UTF-8 before you do any queries. Example: `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');`.

This small article describes the necessary steps to use [UTF-8 for the website](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#utf8).